# How to pass a parameter in Wordpress rest_api_init callback function

Tags: php, wordpress-rest-api

I have 1 problems that I've been trying to solve. I'm trying to follow some examples when I search to do this, and I'm not very successful...been trying to follow stuff like this...
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

1. how do you pass a parameter/args in your callback

this code below does work. The logic I want is that when you pick a day (Y-m-d) format, it return all times available from a start time to an end time chosen by the admin user in wordpress.

here is my rest_api_init

```
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
      register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/day/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
        ) );
} );
```

here is the callback function

```
function my_awesome_func($request) {
        $selected_day = '2020-05-05';
      $startTime = esc_attr( get_option( 'start_time' )); //this works can hard coded as (10:30)
      $endTime = esc_attr( get_option( 'end_time' )); // also works can hard coded (20:00)
      $minutesApart = esc_attr( get_option( 'minutes_between')); //also works hard coded (15)
      $data = array();
              $exploded_daydate = explode('-', $selected_day);
              $start_time_raw = $startTime;
              $end_time_raw = $endTime;
              $start_time_Exploded = (explode(":",$start_time_raw));
              $end_time_Exploded = (explode(":",$end_time_raw));
              $loopStart = mktime($start_time_Exploded[0], $start_time_Exploded[1], 0, $exploded_daydate[1], $exploded_daydate[2], $exploded_daydate[0]);
              $loopEnd = mktime($end_time_Exploded[0], $end_time_Exploded[1], 0, $exploded_daydate[1], $exploded_daydate[2], $exploded_daydate[0]);
              $i=0;
              while ($loopStart <= $loopEnd) {
                $data[$i] = date("Y-d-m h:i:s",$loopStart);
              $loopStart = $loopStart + ($minutesApart *60);
              $i++;
              }
              return $data;
              }
```

right now I hard code ($selected_day = '2020-05-05';) but I want this to work that the endpoint url will work by accepting the (Y-m-d) format at the end of the URL endpoint. I just cant figure it out... new to all of this....

any help would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

never mind... I figured it out... here is the solution I was looking for

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/day/(?P<day>([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])))', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
    
  ) );
} );

    function my_awesome_func($request) {
        $selected_day = $request['day'];
      $startTime = esc_attr( get_option( 'start_time' ));
      $endTime = esc_attr( get_option( 'end_time' ));
      $minutesApart = esc_attr( get_option( 'minutes_between'));
      $data = array();
              $exploded_daydate = explode('-', $selected_day);
              $start_time_raw = $startTime;
              $end_time_raw = $endTime;
              $start_time_Exploded = (explode(":",$start_time_raw));
              $end_time_Exploded = (explode(":",$end_time_raw));
              $loopStart = mktime($start_time_Exploded[0], $start_time_Exploded[1], 0, $exploded_daydate[1], $exploded_daydate[2], $exploded_daydate[0]);
              $loopEnd = mktime($end_time_Exploded[0], $end_time_Exploded[1], 0, $exploded_daydate[1], $exploded_daydate[2], $exploded_daydate[0]);
              $i=0;
              while ($loopStart <= $loopEnd) {
                $data[$i] = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",$loopStart);
              $loopStart = $loopStart + ($minutesApart *60);
              $i++;
              }
              return $data;
              }
```